# Python and numpy - Two Arrays to python function - mean, sd and counts

Tags: python, numpy

Python and Numpy - I am passing two arrays to a python function.

Age array:

```
X =  [35,45,71,25,49]
```

and gender array:

```
T = [male,female,female,male,male]
```

I want to get the mean, standard deviation and count for female and male. I have the below code and it is giving me invalid values. What is the correct code.
numpy version is 1.10.4

```
mF=np.mean(X[T=='Female']);
sdF=np.std(X[T=='Female'],ddof=1);
CF=len(X[T=='Female']);
```

Comment: You might as well use plain Python for this.

Comment: Are X and T numpy arrays to being with?

Comment: Since Python 3.4 / PEP450 there is a [statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html) in the standard library. If you want to use NumPy, make sure to convert the lists to NumPy array as mentioned by BradMcDanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you cast `X` and `T` as numpy arrays and that your capitalization of `'female'` is correct:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([35,45,71,25,49])
T = np.array(['male','female','female','male','male'])

mF=np.mean(X[T=='female']);
sdF=np.std(X[T=='female'],ddof=1);
CF=len(X[T=='female']);
```

Comment: Yes. This works. I was missing cast np.array step.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Awesome - glad it worked. Could you mark it as the right answer by marking the checkmark next to my answer, plz?